# ansible playbook to setup nginx

Tags: ansible

I have written playbook to install ngix on client machine . I got stuck due to some syntactical error. This is my first attempt and I don't understand where exactly the issue is.

Error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to have been in '/private/etc/ansible/nginx.yml': line 6, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
   - name: Installs Nginx r
      apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
         ^ here
```

Playbook:

```
---
   - hosts: myServers
     become: yes
     tasks:
   - name: Installs Nginx r
      apt: pkg=nginx state=installed update_cache=true
      notify:
    - start nginx 

  handlers:
      name: start  nginx
      service: nginx 
      state: started
```

Comment: Have you checked that  `start nginx` is indented correctly? As a side note, I'd use the standard indentation syntax over teh "=" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is wrong. Correct syntax is below.

```
---
- hosts: myServers
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Installs Nginx r
      apt:
        pkg: nginx
        state: installed
        update_cache: true
      notify: start nginx
  handlers:
    - name: start nginx
      service:
        name: nginx
        state: started
```

FWIW. There is an official [Ansible NGINX Role](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx) in active development